# Radio button loses value on postback(after postback first button is again checked)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I select football radio button and when I click on submit and after postback
cricket is selected again.football radio button loses value,

```
<span>
  <input type="radio" id="Cricket" name="SportType" value="1" checked="checked" />Cricket
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" id="Football" name="SportType" value="2" />Football
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" id="Boxing" name="SportType" value="3" />Boxing
</span>
```

***I get correct value on server end***

I am using Asp.net MVC 3
,Firefox 9.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Html.RadioButton` helper to generate radio buttons if you want them to retain values:

```
<span>
    @Html.RadioButton("SportType", "1", new { id = "Cricket" })
    Cricket
</span>
<span>
    @Html.RadioButton("SportType", "2", new { id = "Football" })
    Football
</span>
<span>
    @Html.RadioButton("SportType", "3", new { id = "Boxing" })
    Boxing
</span>
```

Comment: I need unique id and same name.In your case id and name both are same(sportType)

Comment: Following is generated output,i remove span tag <input id="SportType" type="radio" value="1" name="SportType" checked="checked">
Cricket
<input id="SportType" type="radio" value="2" name="SportType">
Football

<input id="SportType" type="radio" value="3" name="SportType">
Boxing

Comment: @kashifilyaz, I have updated my answer with an example of how to specify the id for each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net then there are standard controls which u can make use of them and remember to enable the viewstate in for that control or the while asp.net page

Comment: He's using MVC, so no server side controls.